# How can I use a dependencyManagement version with a classifier with Spring's Gradle dependency management plugin?

Tags: spring, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

Per [dependency-management-plugin#67](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/67), a classifier cannot be specified within the `dependencySet` block.  This limitation is discussed in a related question ([Is it possible to set a dependencySet entry's classifier using Spring's Gradle dependency management plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582771)).

```groovy
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependencySet(group:'com.querydsl', version: '4.2.2') {
            entry 'querydsl-apt' // This needs to use the "general" classifier
            entry 'querydsl-mongodb'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.2:general' // Version needed to use a classifier
  implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb'
}
```

One workaround to this limitation would be to use an [`ext`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) block, and define a version variable:

```groovy
ext {
  querydslVersion = 4.2.2
}

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependencySet(group:'com.querydsl', version: querydslVersion) {
            entry 'querydsl-mongodb'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$querydslVersion:general" // Version needed to use a classifier
  implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb'
}
```

A downside to this approach are that it requires setting a property that wouldn't otherwise be set (and might need to be made available between modules in a multi-module plugin, making the build less obvious).  It also doesn't work particularly well if the dependency version is transitively pulled in via a BOM (e.g. `imports { mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.1.RELEASE'}`, since that requires manually keeping the version in sync with the BOM's value.

Is there still a way to use the version defined in the dependency management section, despite this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Dependency Management Plugin gives programmatic access to the managed versions by way of the [`managedVersions` map](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#working-with-managed-versions-programmatic-access).  This can be used to get the dependency version of the artifact, which can be used to specify the version to use:

```groovy
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${dependencyManagement.managedVersions['com.querydsl:querydsl-apt']}:general"
  implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb'
}
```